# How to append to the URL Path Grails

Tags: url, grails, servlet-filters, url-mapping

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and I'm trying to figure out how to append a state (region) abbreviation (NM, AZ, UT) in the path of my URL. So it looks like this:

```
localhost/NM/action/
```

or

```
localhost/UT/action2/3/
```

This has to be done for all urls on the site. I also don't want to change the URLMappings.groovy file, would a filter help with this?

I created this filter definition:

```
def filters = {
    ...
    regionAppender(uri:'/**') {
        before = {
            if (request.region) {
                if (!request.forwardURI.contains(request.region)) {
                    String[] split = s.split("/");
                    String redirectUri = split[0] + "/" + request.region
                    if (split.length > 1) {
                        for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i++){
                            redirectUri = redirectUri + "/" + split[i]
                        }
                    }
                    redirect(uri: redirectUri)
                    return false
                }
                return true
            }
            return true
            }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working. Is there a way to do this, or do I have change all my URLMappings?

Comment: How do you get NM, UT etc from request? Where is region set to request?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, the request.region is set by another filter definition, which is placed before regionAppender.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't test this but maybe it is to do with your declaration of request... try params.region instead

[Take a look here](http://randomthoughtsofbloggerrandom.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/grails-writing-security-filter-for.html)

```
def filters = {
    ....
            before = {
                if(params?.id) {
```